# Constraint violation when deleting entities

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

Im strugglin with hibernate. I'm trying to delete object BUT I'm getting sql exception.

So first my mappings:

```
@Entity
public class Meetup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime dateAndTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Location location;
```

////////////////////////

```
@Entity
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double longitude;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double latitude;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "location")
    private List<Meetup> meetups;
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
@Entity
public class Match {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meetup_id")
    private Meetup meetup;
```

So I'm trying to delete meetup entity, but by doing that I dont want to delete coresponding Location entity. Now when I'm trying to remove meetup entity (entityManager.remove) I'm getting

```
 constraint ["FKJRLUYUGNHRKYWSVSRE8VE9I9D: PUBLIC.MATCH FOREIGN KEY(MEETUP_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MEETUP(ID) (1)"; SQL statement: delete from meetup where id=? [23503-192]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

The problem can be solved by changing Cascade type to "ALL" on mapping in meetup class, but then obviously my Location entity will be deleted too. And this is something I dont want to happen. So how could I achieve deleting meetup entity without deleting location entity?

Comment: Kindly dump your complete Exception text, so others can assist you better1

Comment: If you want to delete a `Meetup` you need to delete all `Match` entities that reference it first. That might be done by adding a back reference in `Meetup` and adding the corresponding cascade to it. - Note that `Location` isn't part of your problem: "_PUBLIC.MATCH_ FOREIGN KEY(MEETUP_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.MEETUP(ID)".

Comment: yep I have noticed that , but then I have to delete match and by doing that I have constrain on another table (which occured due to ManyToMany relationship) so there I have to delete matches , then I have to delete match, and lastly I can delete meetup. Which kinda sucks because I just wiped the whole Database just to remove meetup. Does my design suck because of that? The case is two users got a match, they decided to do meetup at location X , but then they changed minds nad want to go to location Y, they still like each other (match should stay)  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you simply need to do is make sure you handle the removal of the `MeetUp` as follows within the boundary of a transaction:

```
// Get your meetup by identifier
final Meetup meetup = entityManager.find( Meetup.class, meetupId );

// cleanup the match associations with meetup
entityManager.createQuery( "FROM Match WHERE meetup = :meetup")
      .setParameter( "meetup", meetup )
      .getResultList()
      .forEach( match -> { match.setMeetup( null ); } );

// remove meetup
entityManager.remove( meetup );
```

Given your model, there is no need to fudge with cascade operations for this use case.

Comment: so your saying there is no need to use cascade operations? I tought it is recommended every time, so that I could have up-to-date database with less effort